# Insert into snowflake table from snowflake stream

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake Table1 and I created a stream on Table2. Now I want to check that if there is data in stream based on changes in Table2, then I want to insert the data from the stream into Table1.

How can I insert data into table1 from the stream? Is there a way to check the data in the stream apart from desc stream? I want to see the raw data in stream

Comment: You can always do **SELECT * FROM <stream>** like you would do for a regular table. Remember that any DML operation which includes a SELECT from stream would consume the stream, so be careful there. Otherwise just simple SELECT is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly refer the stream as regular table using query like:

```
Select * from <stream name>;
```

To insert data from stream into Table1

```
Insert into table1 select * from <Stream name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether Stream has data :

```
select system$stream_has_data('<stream_name>');
```

To Insert the data into a table from stream :

```
Insert into Tab1 select ColA, ColB from stream_name;
```

Please do not use select * from stream, as stream contains extra metadata columns which can cause failure.